# Excel - Summary calculation

Tags: excel, sumifs, donations, modulo

Could someone please help me to figure out How to get the summary for every month from the grid in Excel? Please find the following image for the information. Thank you in advance.

[image: Donations Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try with the below formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C3:L9)=2016)*(MOD(COLUMN(C3:L9),2)=1)*(MONTH(C3:L9)=1)*(D3:M9))
```

The above formula is for January. You may need to change the month number 1 in 'MONTH(C3:L9)=1' to 2 for Feb and 3 for Mar and so on.

Comment: If you take the person "S" he has donated 850.00 in that. if I want to extract the total of Feb and March 2016 in one cell and the recent date of donation in another cell. Could you please help me in that? Thank you.

Comment: '=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C3:L9)=2016)*(MOD(COLUMN(C3:L9),2)=1)*(MONTH(C3:L9)=2)*(D3:M9))+SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C3:L9)=2016)*(MOD(COLUMN(C3:L9),2)=1)*(MONTH(C3:L9)=3)*(D3:M9))' is for Feb and March, just add two values

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C3:L9)=2016)*(MOD(COLUMN(C3:L9),2)=1)*(MONTH(C3:L9)=1)*MAX(C3:L9))/SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C3:L9)=2016)*(MOD(COLUMN(C3:L9),2)=1)*(MONTH(C3:L9)=1)) is for your recent date for the month of January